# Why does val range = Range(1, 2, 3, 4) give error?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
for (i <- Array.apply(1 to 4))
      print(i);

Range(1, 2, 3, 4)

Range(1, 10)

//res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

So why does `val range = Range(1, 2, 3, 4)` give error?

Comment: Rather than trying to create a range with `Range(...)`, you could write `val range = 1 to 4`. If you want to add a step, write for example `1 to 9 by 2`. You could write those first two lines as `1 to 4 foreach print`.

Comment: `Array.apply(1 to 4)` produces an `Array[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive]`, which seems rather unorthodox.

Comment: @DanBurton Yes, it is very unorthodox. I expected it to be less surprised. I just tried to create an Array with elements from 1 to 4. The for expression in the example above prints Range(1, 2, 3, 4) which is confusing because I thought it printed the elements of the Array (in fact, it printed the "toString" of the Range object). Range(1, 10) produces Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) is also confusing because you can not add so many arguments to the Range(). I think it's the problem of the presentation (the "toString" method of the object).

Comment: @user477768: a very good point; typically the `toString` function prints out the code that can reproduce the object, so it is quite strange that it prints the elements of the range instead of the arguments.

Comment: @DanBurton That is not true at all. Strings, for instance, are not printed with double quotes. That _some_ things print out in a manner that can reproduce the object is just coincidence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `Range` is a special kind of collection that is restricted in what it can represent in order to efficiently perform its operations.  It is only able to represent a sequence of numbers with a fixed step in between elements.  As such, it only needs to be told about the start, end, and step size in order to be constructed.  An `Array` on the other can hold arbitrary values, so its constructor must be told explicitly what those values are.

The definition of `Range.apply` is that it takes either:

- two arguments: a start and end for a range, or
- three arguments: a start, end, and step size for the range.

Here are the definitions of `apply` from `scala.collection.immutable.Range`:

```
/** Make a range from `start` until `end` (exclusive) with given step value.
 * @note step != 0
 */
def apply(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int): Range = new Range(start, end, step)

/** Make an range from `start` to `end` inclusive with step value 1.
 */
def apply(start: Int, end: Int): Range = new Range(start, end, 1)
```

Constrast this with the `apply` for `scala.Array`, which accepts a variable-length argument `T*`:

```
/** Creates an array with given elements.
 *
 *  @param xs the elements to put in the array
 *  @return an array containing all elements from xs.
 */
def apply[T: ClassManifest](xs: T*): Array[T] = {
  val array = new Array[T](xs.length)
  var i = 0
  for (x <- xs.iterator) { array(i) = x; i += 1 }
  array
}
```

If your goal is to have an `Array` of the numbers 1 to 4, try this:

```
(1 to 4).toArray
```

Comment: There's also the more general `Array.tabulate` where you supply the dimensions and a function describing contents based on its indices, so you don't need a `Range`, e.g. `Array.tabulate(4)(_ + 1)`. But usually you'll just want to use a `Range` directly instead of creating an array, since it's so much cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
scala> Array("abc") // an array containing a string
res0: Array[String] = Array(abc)

scala> Array(1) // an array containing a number
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1)

scala> Array(true) // an array containing a boolean
res2: Array[Boolean] = Array(true)

scala> Array(1 to 4) // an array containing a range
res3: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive] = Array(Range(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Why should it have worked any other way? Anyway, this is what you should have used:

```
scala> Array.range(1, 4)
res4: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```